# How to get selected rows text in the specific cell?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I have a dataGrid which consists of 3 columns  (ID) (Name) (Surname).
How do I get the text of a specific cell of a selected row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SchoolDepartment newPerson = rows[rows.Count - 1];
MessageBox.Show(newPerson.ID.ToString());
```

if the last row is selected

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
private void gridview_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)//Yourcolumindex
            {

                string value = gridview.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();


            }
        }
```

Comment: Isn't it for Gridview only? I'm trying to understand beacouse Your SelectedCells doesn't work with datagrid